# using javascript to format a date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have this little sinppet of JS that returns a date:

```
function dateFormatter(date) {
  return date;
}
```

returns:

> Wed Aug 06 2014 14:43:58 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)

How can i adjust that function so it displays something like: Aug 14

I see the output already does Aug but guess the date 2014 to 14 will need something to adjust on that

Thanks in advance

Comment: Date formatting in JS is a massive pain. You dissect the parts of the date using the built in functions, which will work, but is slow to implement and not internationalised. Alternatively you could use [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) which has all of this taken care of for you.

Comment: If you want light weight write your own that pulls out the month and year. Seems like a very simple thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try with [momentjs](http://momentjs.com):

```
function dateFormatter(date) {
  return moment(date).format('MMM YY');
}
```

With plain JS:

```
function dateFormatter(date) {
  return date.toString().split(' ')[1] + ' ' + date.getFullYear() % 100;
}
```

Comment: It is but want to keep this as light weight as possible without loading plugins etc..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to format from a Date object, use this:

```
function formatDate(date) { //takes a Date object
    var monthArr = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec']; //creates array of month names
    var month = monthArr[date.getMonth()]; //selects array element equal to getMonth(), which ranges from 0-11
    var year = date.getFullYear()%100; //takes the full year (4 digits) mod 100, so the last two digits
    var dateString = month + ' ' + year;
    return dateString;
}
```

If you want to format a string, like the one you provided, use this:

```
function formatDate2(str) { //takes a string
    var dateArr = str.split(' '); //creates array from string, splitting by spaces
    var dateString = dateArr[1] + ' ' + dateArr[3].slice(2,4); //gets element 1 (month) and the last two digits of of element 3 (year)
    return dateString;
}
```